# memoji JS, игра с карточками

Tags: javascript, html, css, dom

При верном открытии всех карточек время должно останавливаться и выскакивать надпись WIN, при нажатии на кнопку на ней карточки должны рандомиться и игра готова к использованию без перезагрузки страницы.

Мы имеем: надпись WIN не вылетает, время не останавливается, а после нажатия на кнопку Lose эмоджи с карточек исчезают

```js
let emoji = ['\u{1F984}', '\u{1F43C}', '\u{1F437}', '\u{1F981}', '\u{1F41E}', '\u{1F438}', '\u{1F984}', '\u{1F43C}', '\u{1F437}', '\u{1F981}', '\u{1F41E}', '\u{1F438}'];
const rotate = document.querySelectorAll('.card');
const emojis = document.querySelectorAll('.emoji');
const front = document.querySelectorAll('.back_card');

let time = 60;
let conditions = randomCard();
const timer = document.querySelector('.timer');
timer.textContent = '0' + (time - time % 60) / 60 + ':' + ((time < 10) ? '0' + time : (time % 60 < 10) ? '0' + time % 60 : time % 60);

const playBtn = document.querySelector('.play');

const endGame = document.querySelector('.end_game');
// Для первого клика 
let isClicked = false;
playBtn.addEventListener('click', newGame);
// let conditions = randomCard();
//массив, в котором будут хранится выбранные карты
let pickArr = []
var intervalId;

function anima_cards(target) {
  if (!isClicked) {
    isClicked = true;
    intervalId = setInterval(gameIter, 1000);
  }
  if (pickArr.length < 2) {
    target.children[0].classList.add('anima_front');
    target.children[1].classList.add('anima_back');
    pickArr.push(target)
  }
  if (pickArr.length == 2) {
    //запускаем проверку на совпадение с некоторой задержкой, т.к. дом дерево надо перерисовать.
    setTimeout(checker, 500)
  }
  if (hasWon()) {
    win();
  }
}

//проверяет совпадение, подствечивает плейсхолдер.
const checker = () => {
  let color = pickArr[0].querySelector('.emoji').textContent == pickArr[1].querySelector('.emoji').textContent ? 'success' : 'fail';
  pickArr.forEach((item) => {
    item.querySelector('.card_placeholder').classList.toggle(color)
  })
  //оканчиваем ход
  setTimeout(finisher, 500, color)
}

//заканчивает ход - отключает плейсхолдер, поворачивает обратно карты, если не угадал.
const finisher = (color) => {
  pickArr.forEach((item) => {
    item.querySelector('.card_placeholder').classList.toggle(color);
    if (color == 'fail') {
      item.children[0].classList.toggle('anima_front');
      item.children[1].classList.toggle('anima_back');
    }
  })
  pickArr = pickArr.slice(-1, 0)
}

rotate.forEach((card) => card.addEventListener('click', ({
  currentTarget
}) => {
  //Если необходимо, здесь вы можете передавать индексы в anima_cards, 
  //т.к. каллбек ф-я forEach вторым аргументом принимает индекс элемента, который можно пробросить дальше
  anima_cards(currentTarget);
}));

function newGame() {
  uncertainCardsNumber = 0

  for (var card of rotate) {
    card.children[0].classList.remove('anima_front');
    card.children[1].classList.remove('anima_back');
  }

  time = 60;
  timer.textContent = '0' + (time - time % 60) / 60 + ':' + ((time < 10) ? '0' + time : (time % 60 < 10) ? '0' + time % 60 : time % 60);
  isClicked = false;
  endGame.classList.add('invisible');
  document.querySelector('.jump:nth-child(4)').classList.remove('invisible');
  conditions = randomCard();
}

function randomCard() {
  emojis.forEach((elem => {
    let max = emoji.length;
    let index = getRandom(0, max);
    elem.textContent = emoji[index];
    emoji.splice(index, 1);
  }));
}

function gameIter() {
  time--;
  timer.textContent = '0' + (time - time % 60) / 60 + ':' + ((time < 10) ? '0' + time : (time % 60 < 10) ? '0' + time % 60 : time % 60);
  if (time == 0) {
    clearInterval(intervalId);
    timeIsOver();
  }
}

function win() {
  showResult(true);
  clearInterval(intervalId);
}

// Функция вызывается при окончании времени, те при поражении 
function timeIsOver() {
  showResult(false);
}

function hasWon() {
  for (var condition of conditions) {
    if (condition['state'] != SOLVED) {
      return false;
    }
  }
  return true;
}

function showResult(res) {
  var spans = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('.jump'));
  var letters;
  if (res) {
    playBtn.textContent = 'Play again';
    letters = ['W', 'i', 'n'];
    spans[3].classList.add('invisible');
  } else {
    playBtn.textContent = 'Try again';
    letters = ['L', 'o', 's', 'e'];
  }
  for (var i = 0; i < letters.length; i++) {
    spans[i].textContent = letters[i];
  }
  endGame.classList.remove('invisible');
}

function getRandom(min, max) {
  return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min)) + min;
}

// randomCard();
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

body {
  height: 100vh;
  background: #cfd0cf;
}

h1 {
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 42px;
  margin: 40px;
  color: #434344;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  line-height: 47px;
}

main {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
}

.memory_card {
  display: grid;
  width: 620px;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(4, 1fr);
  grid-column-gap: 25px;
  grid-row-gap: 25px;
}

.card {
  perspective: 600px;
  cursor: pointer;
  width: 130px;
  height: 130px;
  position: relative;
}

.front_card {
  width: 130px;
  height: 130px;
  background: linear-gradient(45deg, #22AB93, #19668D);
  border: 5px solid white;
}

.back_card {
  width: 130px;
  height: 130px;
  transform: rotateY(180deg);
  background: white;
  text-align: center;
}

.front_card,
.back_card,
.card_placeholder {
  position: absolute;
  box-shadow: 1px 1px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
  transition: 1s;
  border-radius: 9px;
}

.card_placeholder {
  z-index: 100;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  opacity: .5;
}

.emoji {
  margin: 0;
  font-size: 75px;
  line-height: 130px;
}

.anima_back {
  transform: rotateY(360deg);
}

.anima_front {
  transform: rotateY(360deg);
}

.fail {
  background: #F44336;
  z-index: 100;
}

.success {
  background: #5AD66F;
}

.not-active {
  pointer-events: none;
}

.timer {
  font-size: 32px;
  font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
  color: #434344;
  line-height: 36px;
  margin-top: 30px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

.end_game {
  outline: none;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 999;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
}

.result_window {
  display: inline-block;
  min-width: 350px;
  background-color: #CFD0CF;
  margin-top: 15%;
}

.result {
  font-size: 48px;
  font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
  margin: 30px auto 0;
}

.invisible {
  display: none !important;
}

.play {
  color: white;
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 20px;
  font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
  padding: 10px 30px;
  margin: 40px 0 30px;
  background: linear-gradient(45deg, #22AB93, #19668d);
  box-sizing: border-box;
  text-decoration: none;
  box-shadow: 1px 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 1);
}

.play:hover {
  opacity: 0.9;
}

.play:active {
  box-shadow: inset 2px 1px 8px rgba(0, 0, 0, 1);
}

.jump:nth-child(1) {
  display: inline-block;
  animation: jump 1s ease-out infinite;
}

.jump:nth-child(2) {
  display: inline-block;
  animation: jump 1s 0.1s ease-out infinite;
}

.jump:nth-child(3) {
  display: inline-block;
  animation: jump 1s 0.2s ease-out infinite;
}

.jump:nth-child(4) {
  display: inline-block;
  animation: jump 1s 0.3s ease-out infinite;
}

@keyframes jump {
  30% {
    transform: translateY(-10px) scaleY(1.2);
  }
  85% {
    transform: translateY(10px) scaleY(0.7);
  }
}
```

```html
<header>
  <h1>Memoji</h1>
</header>
<main>
  <div class="memory_card">
    <div class="card" data-card="unicorn">
      <div class="front_card"></div>
      <div class="back_card">
        <div class="emoji"></div>
      </div>
      <div class='card_placeholder'></div>
    </div>
    <div class="card" data-card="unicorn">
      <div class="front_card"></div>
      <div class="back_card">
        <div class="emoji"></div>
      </div>
      <div class='card_placeholder'></div>
    </div>
    <div class="card" data-card="raccoon">
      <div class="front_card"></div>
      <div class="back_card">
        <div class="emoji"></div>
      </div>
      <div class='card_placeholder'></div>
    </div>
    <div class="card" data-card="raccoon">
      <div class="front_card"></div>
      <div class="back_card">
        <div class="emoji"></div>
      </div>
      <div class='card_placeholder'></div>
    </div>
    <div class="card" data-card="pig">
      <div class="front_card"></div>
      <div class="back_card">
        <div class="emoji"></div>
      </div>
      <div class='card_placeholder'></div>
    </div>
    <div class="card" data-card="pig">
      <div class="front_card"></div>
      <div class="back_card">
        <div class="emoji"></div>
      </div>
      <div class='card_placeholder'></div>
    </div>
    <div class="card" data-card="tiger">
      <div class="front_card"></div>
      <div class="back_card">
        <div class="emoji"></div>
      </div>
      <div class='card_placeholder'></div>
    </div>
    <div class="card" data-card="tiger">
      <div class="front_card"></div>
      <div class="back_card">
        <div class="emoji"></div>
      </div>
      <div class='card_placeholder'></div>
    </div>
    <div class="card" data-card="bag">
      <div class="front_card"></div>
      <div class="back_card">
        <div class="emoji"></div>
      </div>
      <div class='card_placeholder'></div>
    </div>
    <div class="card" data-card="bag">
      <div class="front_card"></div>
      <div class="back_card">
        <div class="emoji"></div>
      </div>
      <div class='card_placeholder'></div>
    </div>
    <div class="card" data-card="frog">
      <div class="front_card"></div>
      <div class="back_card">
        <div class="emoji"></div>
      </div>
      <div class='card_placeholder'></div>
    </div>
    <div class="card" data-card="frog">

      <div class="front_card"></div>
      <div class="back_card">
        <div class="emoji"></div>
      </div>
      <div class='card_placeholder'></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</main>
<div class='end_game invisible'>
  <div class='result_window'>
    <div class='result'><span class='jump'></span><span class='jump'></span><span class='jump'></span><span class='jump'>e</span></div>
    <a class='play'>Play again</a>
  </div>
</div>
<footer class="timer">01:00</footer>
```

Comment: https://codepen.io/sophie-lamperg/pen/rNeKNYZ

Comment: А что у вас должно по храниться в функции hasWon в conditions - сейчас там undefined. И что за переменная SOLVED ? Ее нигде нет.